# PyQt5 - Definir um InputMask em um QLineEdit para digitar apenas a tecla "F10"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt-5

Tenho uma aplicação que contém um *QLineEdit* que ao estar ativo o usuário tem a opção de pressionar a tecla "F10" e assim abrir outra janela.

Porém gostaria de bloquear esse *QLineEdit* para edição, deixando apenas disponível a tecla "F10"

Com a propriedade **inputMask** consigo fazer isso?

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QShortcut, QLabel

class Tela_1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tela_1, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tela 1 - TESTE")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 400) 

        # ADD WIDGETS
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        # ADD LAYOUT
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        # AO PRESSIONAR A TECLA "F10" CONECTAR COM A FUNÇÃO "abrir_janela2"
        QShortcut(Qt.Key_F10, self.lineEdit,  self.abrir_janela2, context=Qt.WidgetShortcut)

    def abrir_janela2(self):
        self.janela2 = Tela_2()
        self.janela2.show()

class Tela_2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tela_2, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Tela 2 - TESTE")
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 300, 300)   
        self.label = QLabel()
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.label.setText("TELA 2")    

app = QApplication(argv)
w = Tela_1()
w.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta aplicar [`setReadyOnly(true)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#readOnly-prop)

Assim em PyQt5:

```
self.lineEdit.setReadOnly(True)
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado, achei que o setReadOnly não entendia que o QLineEdit estava ativo quando clicado.